# Can not get inline entity form to work with commerce product and room rooms_unit_type

Tags: 7, commerce, entities

I have added an Entity Reference field to a Commerce : Product Type that uses the Inline Entity Form widget.  The reference is to the Bookable Unit Type bundle that is created by the [Rooms](http://drupal.org/projects/rooms) (more specifically, the Rooms Unit module which comes with Rooms).

I have attempted to add the following to `function inline_entity_form_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info)`

```
$entity_info['rooms_unit_type']['inline entity form'] = array(
  'controller' => 'CommerceLineItemInlineEntityFormController',
);
```

The entity reference form never shows when creating new or editing a product.  If I use the autocomplete widget, I am able to select an entity (although that does me no good).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: There is no need to alter the code of a module when any module can implement hooks. Are you sure there is a room_unit_type entity? I would bet that is a content type, aka an entity bundle.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I'm only altering the code to figure out what's going on.  If it's an improvement that can be made with Rooms, and I can fix it, I'll submit a proper patch; alternatively, I would use `hook_entity_info_alter` in a custom module.  Hmm, I'm not sure about the second question.  `room_unit_type` is defined in `hook_entity_info` within the Rooms module.  My goal here is to create new `room_unit_type`'s while adding new products.